# Netty: ChannelProgressiveFutureListener not called using a DefaultFileRegion

Tags: java, listener, netty

I am using a DefaulfFileRegion for downstreaming from my netty based server. While the client receives data, the ChannelProgressiveFutureListener i added to the channel future is never called. I am not very experienced in programming with netty, so i thought i misunderstood how nettys progressive ChannelFuture works. Therfore i looked on example code i found on here: [programcreek.com](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion) . But its basically the same code? I tried finding similar problems here, but couldn't find the reason. Thanks in advance for any hint, why the listener never get's called.

```java
   long todo = file.length () - mRequest.pCursor;
    ctx.writeAndFlush (mFileCursorPacket.encodeInformation (new FileCursor (mRequest.pToken, todo)));


    mFileregion = new DefaultFileRegion (file, mRequest.pCursor, todo);
    ChannelFuture future = ctx.writeAndFlush (mFileregion,ctx.newProgressivePromise ());

    //the listener that is never called!
    future.addListener (new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener () {
        @Override
        public void operationProgressed (ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total) throws Exception {
            O.debug (mSession.getId ()+": downloaded "+progress+" bytes  = "+String.valueOf ((float)progress/(float)total));
        }

        @Override
        public void operationComplete (ChannelProgressiveFuture future) throws Exception {
            boolean success = future.isSuccess ();
            O.info (mSession.getId () + ": downloaded successfull: " + success);
            if (mFileregion != null) mFileregion.release ();
            mFileregion = null;
        }
    });
```

my pipeline looks like this:

```java
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap (); // 
        b.group (mBossGroup, mWorkerGroup).channel (NioServerSocketChannel.class) // 
                //.channel(ServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler (new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> () { // 
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel (SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                        ProtocolMessageInboundHandler inboundHandler = new ProtocolMessageInboundHandler ();
                        inboundHandler.setMessageSizeLimit (MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);
                        ch.pipeline ().addLast (ReadTimeoutHandler.class.getName (), new ReadTimeoutHandler (SO_TIMEOUT_STD));
                        ch.pipeline ().addLast (NAME_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_INBOUND, inboundHandler);
                        ch.pipeline ().addLast (NAME_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_OUTBOUND, new ProtoclMessageOutboundHandler ());

//context passed to the LoginHandler is a ServerContext and has nothing to do with netty
                        ch.pipeline ().addLast (LoginHandler.class.getName (), new LoginHandler (context));
                        ch.pipeline ().addLast (TimeoutHandler.class.getName (), new TimeoutHandler ());


                    }
                }).option (ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128).childOption (ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); // 

        // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
        b.bind (PORT).sync ();
```

while the file-sending handler is inserted after the ProtocolMessageInboundHandler (which modifies byte[] objects only and passes bytebuf objects). So there is no other Handler between the file-sending-handler and ?netty?

Comment: How does your pipeline look?

Comment: i added bootstrap to original post. The handler sending the file is 'in principle' inserted as the first handler in the pipeline

Comment: i can't even get a 'OperationComplete' event, what make's it very hard to use this method (because i want to disable the socket timeout while downloading from server). I would be very thankful for any help (even if it doesn't work with the progess listener)

Comment: Were you able to figure the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a `FileRegion`, you should have a handler in your pipeline that can send such objects. The most commonly used class in Netty for this purpose is the [`ChunkedWriteHandler`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandler.html). This is also used in the [example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/43ebbc3fa065155fa67732b0cbd7c12843b0f3f7/example%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fio%2Fnetty%2Fexample%2Ffile%2FFileServer.java) for `DefaultFileRegion`.

Add the following code to your initializer to make it support `FileRegion`s:

```
ch.pipeline ().addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I added the handler but whether i am using the FileRegion approach or writing with a new ChunkedFile: the listener won't get notified! Both versions deliver the file, but i can't determinate (on server side) when the transfer is finished. The problem with FileRegion was, that because the zero copy thing didnt inject any new byte buf into the pipeline. Tomorrow i will try sending files with ChunkedFile and counting the written bytes in another handler (to notify the promise). Hopefully this helps